# Can't resize React-Player Video

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-player

Can't resize React-Player Video.
I change the width to any number and the video stays unchanged.
I am trying to optimize it for computer view and then add breakpoints to resize for smaller screens like phones.

Bellow is the file where I render the React-Player video inside a  on which I apply the desired height and width I would like my react-player video to adopt.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal'
import { MovieContext } from './MovieContext'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import { getTrailer } from '../utils/movieDB'
// potential of adding controls
// import { Slider, Direction } from 'react-player-controls'
//slider to be implemented
//https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player-controls#playericon-

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  video: {
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    top: '25%',
    right: '25%',
    position: 'fixed',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {},
  },
}))

const styles = {
  player: {
    width: '300px',
  },
}

export default function SimpleModal({ open }) {
  const classes = useStyles(),
    //receives movie from Home > DisplayCard > MovieContext
    { setOpenTrailer, movie, setMovie } = useContext(MovieContext),
    [trailer, setTrailer] = useState(),
    [key, setKey] = useState(),
    [modalStyle] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (movie) {
      getTrailer(movie).then((data) => {
        setKey(data.videos.results[0].key)
        setTrailer(data)
      })
    }
  }, [movie])

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpenTrailer(true)
  }

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpenTrailer(false)
    setMovie(undefined)
    setTrailer(undefined)
    setKey(undefined)
  }

  const renderVideo = (
    <>
      {key && (
        <div className={classes.video}>
          <ReactPlayer style={styles.player} url={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${key}`} />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        open={open || false}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
      >
        {renderVideo}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Which is the proper way to set the dimensions on a react-player object?

Comment: Please paste your css

Comment: As the react-player documentation says, you can use the width and height prop to adjust the width and height of the player.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use react styles to use breakpoints but I'll just use media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the width and height props as such:

```
<ReactPlayer
 width={“300px”}
 url={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${key}`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is from the react-player library. This made my video responsive

its from: https://github.com/cookpete/react-player

```
class ResponsivePlayer extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='player-wrapper'>
        <ReactPlayer
          className='react-player'
          url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U'
          width='100%'
          height='100%'
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

----- CSS ------

```
.player-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25% /* Player ratio: 100 / (1280 / 720) */
}

.react-player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //JSX (works in HTML)
<div className="playerWrapper">
 <ReactPlayer url={sandroCurio} width='100%' height='100%'/>
</div>
</div>)

/*CSS*/
.playerWrapper{width: 60%;height: 90%;margin: auto; position: relative;}
.react-player{ position: absolute; top:0;left: 0;}
.react-player  div{position: absolute; max-width: 50%;}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35121331)